# Recursive vs Iterative Functions Python

Tags: python, recursion, iteration, python-2.x

I am currently learning Python and would like some clarification on the difference between iterative and recursive functions. I understand that recursive functions call themselves but I am not exactly sure how to define an iterative function.

For instance, I wrote this code

```
random_list = ['6', 'hello', '10', 'find', '7']

def sum_digits(string):
    return sum(int(x) for x in string if x.isdigit())

print "Digits:", sum_digits(random_list)
```

I thought that this was an iterative function but after doing some research I am not sure. I need to know specifically because the next exercise asks me to write a version of the function that is recursive/iterative (depending on what my first function is).

Comment: What makes you think this isn't an iterative function?

Comment: A recursive function `F` calls itself, either directly or by calling some other functions that eventually call `F`. Everything else is an iterative function. Simple as that.

Comment: It calling itself is what threw me off.

Comment: It is not calling itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so the question is "write an iterative and recursive version of sum". great.

don't use the built-in sum method, and write your own. i'll give you the iterative, you should figure out the recursive:

```
def my_iterative_sum(a):
    res = 0
    for n in a:
        res += a
    return res
```

this is iterative because it *iterates* over all the values and sums them up.

edit: clearly your post is iterative. are you calling function `f` from within function `f`? no.

maybe reading up on what recursion is will help with this. https://www.google.com/search?q=recursion

Comment: I guess it's worth pointing out that writing a stable recursive `sum` in Python is not an easy fit for a beginner, especially if one doesn't not what recursion is.

Comment: I thought that a recursive function called itself which is why I thought it wasn't iterative even though I know that it was repeating itself over every item. But thanks!

Comment: i know what you're saying, but where in your example is there a function calling itself?

Comment: Looking at it again after sleeping makes me wonder why I thought that to be honest. I can see that it is clearly iterative now haha. Thanks again for your help

Comment: hey, glad you got it sorted! were you able to implement the recursive func?

Comment: I have not been able to :( I understand the difference but I am not sure how I would convert my original function into a recursive function.

Comment: this is a little late, but it's a different algorithm you'll have to use. read this and instead of decrementing a number, decrease the number of elements in your list: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/recursion/

Comment: @acushner this type of recursion is inefficient (and dangerous) in Python (or in any non-functional language for that matter). It's better to consider https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tail-recursion/. Even so, Python does not optimise tail calls itself, making it necessary to resort to third-party solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Recursive function call itself while does not reach the out poin whereas iterative function update calculating value through the iteration over the range.

Answer (score 2):

To those who might still want to see the difference between recursive and iterative function.

iterative

```
def iterative_sum(n):
    result = 1
    for i in range(2,n+1):
        result *= i
    return result
print(iterative_sum(5))
```

iteration is when a loop repeatedly executes until the controlling condition becomes false

recursive

```
def recursive_sum(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * recursive_sum(n-1)
print(recursive_sum(5))
```

recursive function is when a function calls itself

This link explains it much better 
https://techdifferences.com/difference-between-recursion-and-iteration-2.html

Answer (score 0):

In case you came here looking for recursive functions in Python, here is an example of a recursive sum

```py
from typing import Optional

>>> def r_sum(v: int, sum: Optional[int] = None) -> int:
...   if sum is None:
...     sum = 0
...   if v == 0:
...     return sum
...   else:
...     sum = sum + v
...     prev = v - 1
...     return r_sum(prev, sum)
... 
>>> r_sum(3)
6
>>> r_sum(4)
10
>>> r_sum(5)
15
```